# Removing space from table column

Tags: html

I have a table with two image column and and 2 image row. I don't want any space but still there is some space between two image column.
How can I remove the space?

```
<html>
```

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="602">
            <tr><td>

                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="602">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="290">
                            <a href="[EMV LINK]305[EMV /LINK]" ><img alt="A-Frame detail from Ambrose at heals"  src="images/208662650.jpg"  width="290" align="right" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="290">
                            <a href="[EMV LINK]305[EMV /LINK]" ><img alt="A-Frame detail from Ambrose at heals" src="images/961251218.jpg"  width="290" align="left" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="290">
                            <a href="[EMV LINK]305[EMV /LINK]" ><img alt="A-Frame detail from Ambrose at heals"  src="images/665050103.jpg"  width="290" align="right" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="290">
                            <a href="[EMV LINK]305[EMV /LINK]" ><img alt="A-Frame detail from Ambrose at heals"  src="images/1380993378.jpg"  width="290" align="left" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                </td></tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: What space? Works as expected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ybd729eL/)

Comment: 10 + 290 + 290 + 6 doesn't equal 602 - the space will be caused by your cells adjusting to fit the width properly.  Also the `width` attribute shouldn't use px - eg `width="290"`.  Make both your side cells 11px and it should sort your problem

Comment: By the way unless this is an email template, you shouldn't be using tables for layout

Comment: This is a email template . I have updated with 11 still didn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
border-spacing: 0px
```

Shoud work fine for you. Just define it in your CSS File

Comment: cellspacing="0" is the same thing

Comment: border-spacing: 0px didn't help. It works fine on Firefox, issue is with IE